# Jira JQL decode Monday Tuesday etc

Tags: jira, jql, kanban

Has anyone managed to create a query that returns data based on Monday Tuesday Wednesday next week?

I can get a result with `startofweek(1)` and `endofweek(1)` but that doesn't break down to each day.

Ideally I'd get a result like this:

```
Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
--------------------------------------------------
Card1              Card1
         Card3                Card4
                   Card5
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is not possible. Columns on Jira boards are configurable by issue status, not via JQL. However, you could do the following:

1) Add a quickfilter for each weekday. JQL actually is more powerful as it looks on first sight: You can use expressions like "status changed ON ..." - enabling you to observe issues that were touched at these days. This would per filter show a single day only on the board, since filters are internally combined via AND.

2) Do the same JQL but with swim lanes. You could see each day on the board at the same time in a separate swimlane. But I consider this mind-twisting.

You should write a more elaborate JQL that fits what exactly you want to see, of course. There is another way, though you'd need (low) programming skills:

3) Use Jira REST API to fetch your sprint/week data and throw it in a grid that suits your needs yourself.